# "support" tag on meta

Tags: feature-request

The "support" tag on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ is described as "A request for assistance with one of the site's features, **or a question where you're expecting a concrete answer, and not discussion.** If your question is not reporting a bug, requesting a new feature, or soliciting open discussion, this tag is probably the right one."

The "support" tag on https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/ is described as "You need help with the use of one or more of the site's features."

What is the appropriate tag on https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/ for questions "where you're expecting a concrete answer, and not discussion"? Maybe the description of the "support" tag should be updated.

Comment: I believe this is just the standard language on all the meta sites; not sure why the main meta is different. If you are asking with respect to your other question https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/spirit-behind-the-term-biological-concept-in-the-help-center "discussion" is the correct tag, not "support." This is a small enough site that the meta tags are probably not too important, though.

Comment: @BryanKrause In the other question "discussion" is rather *not* the correct tag. I'm not asking for a discussion ("opinions or best-practices") there. I'm asking to disclose what exactly the guideline-makers had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  The original definition for [support](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) was the one which still exists on biology:

> A request for assistance with one of the site's features

The meta tag changed back in July 2018.  Interestingly, it was not a diamond user who proposed or reviewed [the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58549), so presumably there were a few people who were finding that the support tag was getting too conversational.

I assume that it was basically an attempt to make it clear that [support](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) was not for *discussing* features on the site but for requesting help with them.  For discussions related to anything on the site, use [discussion](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

I should mention that the "company approved" definition of the tag is the shorter one, used on newly launched sites.

Personally, I think it would be fine to change the tag's definition for the longer definition or something which emphasised the search for concrete answers, but honestly, the volume of questions we get on meta.biology (unlike on the main meta) is low enough that it really makes no difference.